# Is my website loading while the spinner is shown?

Tags: css, reactjs, loading

This is the `App.js`

```
import Newhome from './COMPONENTS/Newhome';
import HashLoader from "react-spinners/HashLoader";
import { useState ,  useEffect } from 'react';
import "./App.css";
function App() {
  const [loading, setloading] = useState(false);
  useEffect(() => {
    setloading(true);
    setTimeout(() => {
      setloading(false);
    }, 1785);
  }, [])
  return (
    <>
      {
        <>
          {
          loading ?
            <div className="App">
              <HashLoader className='loader' color={'#FF5757'} loading={loading}
                size={120} />
            </div>
            : (<Newhome />)
          }
        </>
      }
    </>
  );
}

export default App;
```

I am not sure if the website is loading while I am showing the spinner. I think the spinner is only shown for some seconds and after the website is shown without loading.

What is happening here?

This is the website [My website](https://ankitsinghchauhan.tech)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use efffect runs after the render. Essentially is you're trying to show the spinner before the website loads then this is not the best approach. You can try code spliitting i.e

```
import React, { Suspense } from 'react';

import HashLoader from "react-spinners/HashLoader";
const Newhome  = React.lazy(() => import('./COMPONENTS/Newhome'));

function App() {
  return (
    <div>
      <Suspense fallback={<HashLoader/>}>
        <Newhome />
      </Suspense>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Will this load the website while the spinner moves??

Comment: yes...the spinner loads first then the first page is painted soon as react is ready to render. Try and see if it gets you the desired effects.

Comment: Can you explain what was happening before  @narravabrion

Comment: The useEffect with an empty array runs once after the page is rendered. In your initial code during the initial render loading is `false` by default so the `Newhome` component is rendered. Then the useEffect runs and loading is set to `true` so the `HashLoader` is rendered instead of the `NewHome` and after the timeout, loading is false again and the `NewHome` is rendered again. This was the sequence of renders `NewHome` -> `HashLoader` -> `NewHome`.

Comment: Hope the solution I offered gave you the desired effect

Comment: yes, it did, but sometimes the background image takes some time after loading.

Comment: I noticed. Essentially the important parts of the site are loaded first i.e html/jsx is given priority then media content. The faster the internet connection the faster the load time for any media.